# JavaEE 7 and Socket.io

Tags: web-applications, websocket, socket.io

I have a web application which uses socket.io to connect to my node.js server. Now i have some implementations in java and wants the same client to communicate with Java server side. How does my current socket.io client can connect to a java back end ?

Answer (score 0):

You should at least try before asking this kind of question.

Socket.io does support websocket as transport, so it will work if and only if websocket transport is used.

Comment: socket.io uses websocket as transport is a known fact.i think you have not gotten my point i have modified the question. what i am actually looking for is a socket.io server implementation for java like the one it has for node.js

Comment: you should work on your question little bit more, it is still unclear what you really want to know.

Comment: the link is new to me and the socket.io-netty library is something that i was looking for. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could run [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) on java  to connect with your socketio clients.

Comment: yes. i was thinking of using something like this. but then came [vertx](http://vertx.io) platform which is polygot and supports java with socketio library. Using that and is great!